# .NET Core vs .NET Framework / C# console application - method not working

Tags: c#, .net

So I made a mistake and instead of creating a project as C# Console Application I 
created .NET Core one. It is a simple game (Conway's Game of life) and one of the things implemented is creating a random board (2D Array), transforming it and then printing it to the console.

The random board generation works fine in .NET Core however if I try to paste my cs files including Program.cs to .NET Framework or C# app everything seems to be working except said random generation. When I debug it also seems to be working fine but at the point of returning the randomly generated board from GenerateRandom in BoardGenerator.cs it returns an array of all true values or all false values.

I have not changed a single line of code, I tried to delete all build files and re-build, nothing works and it is driving me nuts.

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        var game = new Game();

        Console.WriteLine("CONWAY'S GAME OF LIFE");
        Console.WriteLine();

        var folder = @"D:\_programming projects\game-of-life\GameOfLife\patterns\";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");

        for (var i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + 1 + ": " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i]));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(files.Length + 1 + ": Random");

        Console.Write("Enter number to load board: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        int.TryParse(input, out var option);
        option--;

        try
        {
            if (option == files.Length)
                game.SetBoard(new BoardGenerator().GenerateRandom(Constants.BoardRows, Constants.BoardColumns));
            else
                game.SetBoard(new BoardGenerator().GenerateFromFile(
                    files[option],
                    Constants.BoardRows,
                    Constants.BoardColumns));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");

        }

        game.PrintBoard();

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.Clear();
            game.MutateBoard();
            game.PrintBoard();
        }
    }
}
```

**BoardGenerator.cs**

```
    public class BoardGenerator
{
    private readonly bool[] _values = { true, false };
    private bool[,] _board;

    public bool[,] GenerateRandom(int noRows, int noColumns)
    {
        _board = new bool[noRows, noColumns];

        BoardProcessor.ProcessValue(_board, tile => _values[new Random().Next(0, _values.Length)]);

        return _board;
    }

    [...]

}
```

**BoardProcessor.cs**

```
    public static class BoardProcessor
{
    public static void ProcessValue(bool[,] board, Func<bool, bool> func)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
                board[i, j] = func(board[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Again, this code works in .NET Core. What's the problem?

Comment: Standard bug, you must create the Random object only once.  If you do it over and over again then it is seeded with the same value (the current time) and produces the same random number.  Seems to work correctly only when you debug, slowing the code down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Framework and .NET Core have different implementation of `Random` default constructor. Both try to generate some default seed to start the pseudo-random sequence with, but ways they generate the seed are different. In particular the .NET Core implementation uses internal global random objects to generate random seed which guarantees different seeds for all sequential calls of `new Random()`. The Framework implementation however uses `Environment.TickCount` as a seed, which imposes the risk that sequential calls of `new Random()` which are called quickly enough  will get the same seed (because ticks count isn't updated during the instances initialization period) which int turn means the same pseudo-random sequence for all instances of `Random` initialized in that period with default constructor. That's what most likely happens in your case. The fix is simple - as suggested use single instance of `Random` initialized before `BoardProcessor.ProcessValue` call.